# Why can I access constants inside an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Say I have:

```
class MyClass
  MY_ENUM = [MY_VALUE_1 = 'value1', MY_VALUE_2 = 'value2']
end
```

Something like this is possible:

```
p MyClass::MY_VALUE_1 #=> "value1"
```

Why? Isn't `MY_VALUE1` and `MY_VALUE_2` constant scope inside the `[]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the nested constant `MY_VALUE_1` because it is in the same scope as the outer constant `MY_ENUM`: Both constants are in the scope of class `MyClass`.

You expected the `[...]` construct to define a new scope, but it does not.  In Ruby, only three things define a new scope:

- Defining a class using `class SomeName`
- Defining a module using `module SomeName`
- Defining a function using `def some_name`

Answer (score 2):

An array literal (`[...]`) defines no scope. You seem to want a hash:

```
class MyClass
  MY_ENUM = {:MY_VALUE_1 => "value1", :MY_VALUE_2 => "value2"}
end 

MyClass::MY_ENUM[:MY_VALUE_1] #> value1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent visibility outside the class (hiding) you can use 'private_constant'

```
private_constant :MY_VALUE_1
```